# Schedule a function that belongs to an R package

Tags: r, linux, bash, postgresql, package

I'm trying to build an R package whose goal is to run a series of analyses by taking input data and writing output data to an external database (PostgreSQL).

Specifically, I need a set of operations to be scheduled to run on a daily basis. Therefore, I have written some bash scripts with R code (using the header `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript`) and I have saved them into the `exec/` folder of the R package. The scripts make several call to the package's core functions in `R/` folder.

At this point, once installed the package on a linux server, how do I set up a crontab that is able to directly access the scripts in the `exec/` folder?

Is this way of proceeding correct or is there a different *best practice* for such operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do this *all the bleeping time at work*. Here at home I also have a couple of recurring cronjobs, eg for [CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries).   The `exec/` folder you reference works, but my preferred solution is to use, say, `inst/scripts/someScript.R`.

Then one initial time you need create a softlink from your package library, say, `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/myPackage/scripts/someScript.R` to a directory in the `$PATH`, say `/usr/local/bin`.

The key aspect is that the softlink persists even as you update the package.  So now you are golden.  All you now need is your crontab entry referencing `someScript.R`.  We use a mix of `Rscript` and [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk! Indeed it is a continuous activity, so I was wondering if someone more experienced than me had devised the best way to handle it. One more question for you: once the package is installed, the scripts will be able to see the other objects inside the `inst/` folder and to access them like codes in `R/` folder do, e.g. `system.file('foo/hello.txt', package = 'my_package')`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Plenty of examples here, in the manual, in other packages.